# Which data structure is like a combination of a doubly-linked list and an array?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is there any already created structure which would be simply `basic array` of `doubly linked list nodes`?

I mean then you use `get(int index)` it would return element directly from array (`array[i].element`). With this structure I could easily do foreach too because every element would be linked to each other, so I would not need to think about blank array places.

Q: Why I need this ?
A: I have unlimited memory, I know how big array I need and I want that structure would be fastest.

Comment: Are you looking for a `std::array<std::list, some_size>`?

Comment: Maybe  `std::deque`?

Comment: @NathanOliver It seems OP wants an array of nodes, not an array of lists.

Comment: Yes I want array of nodes. Node contains left node, right node and element.

Comment: it's either a linked list, or an array, there is no hybrid. the best I can think of is an array of pointers to nodes.

Comment: I could create this structure myself but I'm looking maybe it's already created.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do linear searches when inserting a new node, to link the linked-list parts though?

Comment: You have commented the `get` usage, but not the whole use case. It is very difficult to answer the "fastest" alternative if we do not know how you will use it (adds, lookups, removals, batch operations...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small *C++11 container guide*, just set your constraints and follow the arrows:

[image]

IMO [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/) is the most probable candidate.

In case you want to create something yourself, here is an example of how could it look like:

```
struct Node{
    // constructor
    Node (int v, Node* n = 0, Node* p = 0) 
        : value(v), next(n), prev(p) { }

    // data member
    int value;
    // pointer to next node
    Node* next;
    // pointer to previous node
    Node* prev;
};

size_t number_of_nodes = 10;
Node* ptr = new Node[number_of_nodes];
```

Comment: Now I'm thinking that adding new element in "my structure" would be like doubly linked list which means that complexity would be about O(n). Other functions complexity would be like `std::deque`. So I think your answer is closest to answer.

Comment: So you were just looking for a vanilla node?

Comment: I was looking for structures which would be as fast in adding, removing and getting elements as array. Also I needed foreach loop. In basic array if I do foreach loop then I need to deal with empty array places, so I thinked about continuosly linking elements to neighour in array and then I could just skip this empty array places.

Comment: @Vinigas All standard containers support for each loop. Even normal arrays do: http://ideone.com/Q2212M

Comment: You used integer array, but if I use the pointer array then I don't want to throgh array elements which countains NULL. `for_each` goes through every single array element. E.g. I have array which size is 100. Whole array is filled with NULLs. Then I add two element's in array with random index. And then I do for_each I actually want to do loop only 2 times, not 100.

Comment: Err, alright. I don't see how a container can do this when `std::for_each` takes a `_begin_expr` and an `_end_expr`, which return iterators to the where you want to begin and end applying the function. I don't think _any_ of the answers have really addressed that, which I would call an XY problem anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, I think the most fitting data structure would be a double-ended queue; or, in C++, a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

## How it's like a doubly-linked list:

- Stores back and front pointers

  - `{push,pop}_{front,back}` are `O(1)`
- Doesn't need reallocs when expansion is necessary

## How it's like an array:

- Allows subscript indexing

  - `O(1)` random access

The `get` operation you're looking for is `operator[]` or `std::deque::at`.

Some considerations are that insertion/removal of elements not on polar ends of the structure (i.e., somewhere in the middle) are average case `O(n)` on the number of elements for the same reason it's `O(n)` to remove an element from a basic array.

[Obligatory basic-use-case](http://ideone.com/KSfn4D)

Comment: by _"bracket indexing"_ do you mean `subscript operator[ ]`? :)

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Edited. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the container deque already present in the STL. See -> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque
If it is not the one you are looking for, you probably find the container you need here --> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Hope this help